# statsd fails to send data to Influxdb

Tags: influxdb, statsd

I want to use statsd + influxdb + grafana to construct a monitor systerm. But I find that my statsd can't send data to influxdb successfully.
The configure of statsd is as follow:

```
{
  influxdb: {
    host: '127.0.0.1', // InfluxDB host (default 127.0.0.1)
    port: 8086, // InfluxDB port (default 8086)
    version: 1.0,
    database: 'statsd',  // InfluxDB db instance (required)
    username: 'root', // InfluxDB db username (required)
    password: 'root', // InfluxDB db password (required)
    flush: {
      enable: true // enable regular flush strategy (default true)
    },
    proxy: {
      enable: false, // enable the proxy strategy (default false)
      suffix: 'raw', // metric name suffix (default 'raw')
      flushInterval: 1000
    }
  },
  port: 8125, // statsD port
  backends: ['./backends/console', 'statsd-influxdb-backend'],
  debug: true,
  legacyNamespace: false
}
```

And the error message is like that:

```
13 Sep 18:58:52 - [influxdb] (DEBUG) Sending 1 different points via HTTP
13 Sep 18:58:52 - [influxdb] (DEBUG) Payload size 0.09 KB
13 Sep 18:58:52 - [influxdb] HTTP Error: 400
```

Is there anybody can help me?Thanks a lot.

Comment: What versions of statsd and influxdb are you using?

Comment: Thank you. I used influxdb v1.0. And I found that the statsd-influxdb-backend didn't support it. The API it sended is not correct. Then I hacked the code of statsd-influxdb-backend, it works for my situation.